# Use jQuery plugin from asynchronously loaded external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-plugins

I have a very basic jQuery plugin which I load into my webpage like so:

```
(function() {
    var tk = document.createElement('script');
    tk.src = '//www.test.com/scripts/jq_plugin.js';
    tk.type = 'text/javascript';
    tk.async = 'true';
    tk.onload = tk.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var rs = this.readyState;
        if (rs && rs != 'complete' && rs != 'loaded') return;
    };
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(tk, s);
})();
```

Then, I call the plugin like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').jq_plugin();
});
```

But when the page loads I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function)
```

I understand why - the plugin is being called before the script is loaded. I know a quick and dirty hack is just to use a `setTimeout()` around the plugin call but I don't want to do that. I've tried inserting the script before and after jQuery but get the same result.

How can I do this without a timeout?

This is a stripped down version of the plugin:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.jq_plugin = function(options){
        return this.each(function() {
            return $(this).click(onClick);
            function onClick(e){
                console.log('ID: '+$(this).attr('id'));
            }           
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Call the plugin in the `onreadystatechange` handler function.

Comment: I don't really want to do that. The snippet that loads the script is for people to download and add to their site. The plugin serves as an API of sorts. There could also be a large number of elements calling the plugin.

Comment: That's the nature of loading things asynchronously. Anything that depends on it has to be done in the callback.

Comment: Why don't they just put `<script>` tags into their HTML? Or perhaps you should look at how RequireJS does things.

Comment: The reason I have avoided `<script>` tags is because I don't want the script to affect the load times of any pages it is added to. Will look into RequireJS, thanks.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it. If you want the script to load asynchronously, then you have to use async programming methods to use it.

Comment: Sadly this is true. Similar problem discussed here and good info on RequireJS for anyone else interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915201/why-use-something-like-require-js-rather-than-simply-creating-a-script-element

Answer (score 1):

You create an onload/onreadystatechange, but all it does is return. You need to be checking that before you try and call the plugin.

You could either put your code that uses the plugin inside of that onload function

```
tk.onload = tk.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var rs = this.readyState;
    if (rs && rs != 'complete' && rs != 'loaded'){
         $(function(){
              $('#test').jq_plugin();
         });
    }
};
```

Of you could set a boolean `tkHasLoaded = false` and then set it to true in the onload function. Check that before trying to use the plugin.

Comment: The flag wouldn't help, because there's no way to go back and check it again.

Comment: Also, weirdly it stops me getting the error but the plugin becomes unresponsive. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Barmar Just make the flag a global variable.

Comment: That doesn't help. You can't check it in a loop, because while the loop is running it prevents the asynchronous loading of the script.